# Why don't loops take long as a valid type in its conditions?

Tags: java, loops, netbeans, long-integer

I am working on some Project Euler exercises and need to use extremely large numbers.
I still need to use some basic loops like for-loops or while loops.

My IDE ,Netbeans, is giving me an error I can't wrap my head around.

```
    long l = 10000000000L;
    while (l<10000000000000){

    }
    for (long k =0;k<10000000000000;k++){

    }
```

On both loops I get the remark : "Integer number too large : 10000000000000"
How can it talk about integers while I am clearly working with 'long' ?
Are these loops only meant for 'int'? 
And if so ,how would I go about having the same functionality with 'long' as type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is as easy as it looks like :)

```
    long l = 10000000000L;
    while (l < 10000000000000L) {

    }
    for (long k = 0; k < 10000000000000L; k++) {

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an `l` (or `L`) suffix to mark the number as a `long`:

```
while (l<10000000000000l){

}
for (long k =0;k<10000000000000l;k++){

}
```

Otherwise the number is treated as an integer and it's higher than the maximum value in the integer range (`2147483647`).